# NavBar outside Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

App.js

```
 return (
<div>
  <NavBar />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}></Route>
    <Route path='/login' render={() => userCredentials.email ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Form />}></Route>
    <Route path='/register' render={() => userCredentials.email ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Form />}></Route>
    <Route path='/About' component={About}></Route>
    <Route path='/Plot' component={Plot}></Route>
    <Route path='/Profile' component={Profile}></Route>
  </Switch>
</div> );}
```

I need NavBar to be on every page, so I place it outside the Switch component. However, I lost the match prop from withRouter when doing this (match.url or path is '/'), which is a great shame, since I need it too. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple routes match at the same time. You could try something like this to have a route match `/` without the exact flag:

```js
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/' component={NavBar} /> // Will render on every route
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}></Route>
    <Route path='/login' render={() => userCredentials.email ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Form />}></Route>
    <Route path='/register' render={() => userCredentials.email ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Form />}></Route>
    <Route path='/About' component={About}></Route>
    <Route path='/Plot' component={Plot}></Route>
    <Route path='/Profile' component={Profile}></Route>
  </Switch>
```